# How do I set the value of multiple checkboxes that is linked to an associated table because of many-to-many relationship MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a checkbox where the user can choose a number of services that can be provided to a company. I can save the services and that all works fine. The services are linked to a company through a CompanyService table which as the companyId and the serviceId.

If the user clicks on an edit button I am unsure how to have the boxes checked on load. I've had a look at other options using IsChecked however I cannot add a property to my services model as it serves multiple companies. How would I go about doing it?

My Service Model

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CompanyService> CompanyServices { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TrustService> TrustServices { get; set; }
```

My CompanyService model

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order =1)]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order =2)]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
```

And finally the Razor code

```html
<div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <ul class="list-group" id="serviceList">
                        <li class="list-group-item service-heading">Services</li>
                        @foreach (var service in Model.Services)
                        {
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="services" value="@service.Id" id="check_@service.Id" />
                                <label for="check_@service.Id">@service.Name</label>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Do I need to create a IsChecked on my CompanyServices table and try and assign the checked value from there? If so how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to create a IsChecked on my CompanyServices table and try
>   and assign the checked value from there? If so how would I do that?

Yes, you need to create `boolean` type of property inside your model so that you can use Razor's strongly typed HTML helper for Checkbox.

Updated code is below.

```html
<div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <ul class="list-group" id="serviceList">
                        <li class="list-group-item service-heading">Services</li>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Services.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                             @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Services[i].Id)
                             @Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.Services[i].IsChecked)
                          
                                <label for="@Html.IdFor(model=>model.Services[i].IsChecked)">@Model.Services[i].Name</label>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**PS:** Note the HiddenFor helper for `Id`. which will maintain the relation between `Id` and its checkbox's value (checked/unchecked) at server side for model binding.

Comment: But my service model only stores the names of the services. the actual services are linked to the company through the CompanyService model. Surely if I use this method the same services will be checked for each company?

Comment: Ok. What is the type of `Model.Services` in your Razor code?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, don't use a foreach.  It won't create the proper bindings for model binding the values back to your model.  Use a for, as in `for (int i = 0; i < Model.Services.Count; i++)`

Secondly, you need to use the indexer in your checkboxes.

Finally, use CheckboxBox as in `@Html.CheckboxFor(x => x.Services[i].Id)`,

Comment: `Html.CheckboxFor` accepts only boolean type of model property in expression. So `@Html.CheckboxFor(x => x.Services[i].Id)` wont work as `Id` is `int`. He has to create new property of type `boolean`.

Comment: Why does the foreach not bind correctly? thanks for the advice. my service model only stores the names of the services. the actual services are linked to the company through the CompanyService model. Surely if I use this method the same services will be checked for each company?

Comment: @MattRichardTowers - Because it does not create indexers, thus it will not create a proper collection on postback.  You just use a for statement to get the index created in the name.